# Azure Data Factory Table Storage Conversion Error

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to get data from Azure Table Storage using Azure Data Factory. I have a table called orders which has 30 columns. I want to take only 3 columns from this table (PartitionKey, RowKey and DeliveryDate). The DeliveryDate column has different data types like DateTime.Null (String value) and actual datetime values. When I want to preview the data i get the following error:

[image]

The DataSource looks like this:

```
{
"name": "Orders",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "AzureTableStorage",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "AzureTable",
    "structure": [
        {
            "name": "PartitionKey",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "RowKey",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "DeliveryDate",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ],
    "typeProperties": {
        "tableName": "Orders"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I test your problem,it works.Can you show me more detail about this or there is something wrong about my test?

Below is my test data:

[image: table]

[image: entity]

[image: preview]

The dataset code:

```
{
    "name": "Order",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureTableStorage",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureTable",
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "PartitionKey",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "RowKey",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "DeliveryDate",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "tableName": "Table7"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is how Data Factory inference the data type. If you add the first value in DeliveryDate to be DateTime and afterwards String you will encounter the error.

Comment: Yes,you are right.When I change the first type from 'string' to 'datetime',the error comes.It seems decided by first row's type.When I first row's type is 'string',other row's type is 'datetime' it can be converted successfully.So you can change the first row's type to 'string'.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the source data. And this issue is happening for lots of tables. I have values like DateTime.Null which is string and other rows with actual datetime value